# How to Create Sub Menu by Finding "_" Underscore in <li> Links using JavaScripts or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want Convert this HTML code into

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">_Sub Menu  Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">_Sub Menu Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">DMCA</a></li>
</ul>
```

this HTML code using Javascript or jQuery, i am working on blogger templates for create a menu system

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="has-menu">Sub Menu</a>
 <ul class="sub-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu  Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">DMCA</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new HTML(with nested Sub Menus) using an array of objects instead of parsing and finding '_' underscore in your current HTML for sub-menu. Please, find the running code as below:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jmgsck5/)

*menu.html*

```
<ul id="major"></ul>
```

*menu.js*

```
const arr = [{
  name: 'Home',
}, {
  name: 'Sub Menu',
  menus: ['_Sub Menu  Item', '_Sub Menu Item']
}, {
  name: 'DMCA',
}];

const getSub = (item) => {
  let li = '';
  item.menus.forEach(x => {
    li += '<li><a href="#">' + x + '</a></li>'
  });
  return '<ul class="sub-menu">' + li + '</ul>';
}
let li = '';

arr.forEach(item => {
  if (item.menus) {
    const getUL = getSub(item);
    li += '<li><a href="#" class="has-menu">' + item.name + '</a>' + getUL + '<li>';
  } else {
    li += '<li><a href="#">' + item.name + '</a></li>';
  }
});
$('#major').append(li);
```